# printing of integers mips

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I try to add numbers to a array and then I try to print those numbers, but when I add mine numbers and I try to print and then I got different numbers. How is that possible?

My code is:

```
#----------------------------------- Array Vullen  -----------------------------------------------------
.data
    question1_msg: .asciiz "How much integer do you want to give?\n"
    question2_msg: .asciiz "give a number?\n"
.text

question_numbers:
    la $a0, question1_msg #load the question in $a0
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

answer_numbers: 
    li $v0, 5  #read the answer of previous question
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0
    move $t9, $t0
    move $t8, $t0

generate_array:   
    sll $t0, $t0, 2 #create array
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 9
    syscall
    move $t3, $v0 #put the stack pointer in a temperay register
    move $t4, $v0

add_numbers_array:
    bge $t1, $t9, Call_procedure # if $t1 >= $t0 then exit

    #ask questions
    la $a0, question2_msg #load the question in $a0
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #read numbers
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t2, $a0

    #add number en go to the next array point
    sw $t2, ($t3)
    add $t3, $t3, 4
    add $t1, $t1, 1

    #get back to the begin of the loop
    b add_numbers_array

#-------------------------------------Array Printen------------------------------------------------


Call_procedure:
    li $t1, 0
    la $a1, ($t8)    # load the couple of numbers
    la $a2, ($t4)    # load the starting adress of the array
    jal Print
    b exit

Print:
    bge $t1, $a1, return  # if $t1 >= $t0 then exit
    lw $t2, ($a2)  #load integer and print
    move $a0, $t2
    li $v0, 1      # print the number in the array
    syscall    


    addu $a2, $a2, 4  #increase the sp
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    #increase the number printed

    b Print

return:
    jr $ra

exit:
li $v0 , 10 # let the code end
syscall
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you. Just wanted to thank you for your nice, clean code. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 errors:

1.

```
#read numbers
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t2, $v0
```

This should be $v0, not $a0

2.

```
move $a1, $t8
move $a2, $t4
```

instead of

```
la $a1, ($t8)    # load the couple of numbers
la $a2, ($t4)    # load the starting adress of the array
```